# C# A generic error occurred in GDI+ after save cropped image

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, gdi+

I have two steps for upload and save images, In the first step, image is uploaded and a preview shown to the user for cropping and in the second step with a JQuery plugin user select intended area and click crop image button.

At bellow you can see `CropImage()` Action.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> CropImage(UploadImage data)
{
    string fileName = data.fileName;
    string path;

    path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/UsersImages/"), fileName);
    data.url = "https://example.com/Images/UsersImages/" + fileName + "?crop=" + data.x1 +
               "," + data.y1 + "," + data.x2 + "," + data.y2 + "&&width=309&&height=411&mode=max";

                  
    Bitmap img = new Bitmap(data.GetStreamFromUrl());
    img.Save(path);
  
}
```

And here is `UploadImage` class:

```
public class UploadImage
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string x1 { get; set; }
    ...


    public Stream GetStreamFromUrl()
    {
        byte[] imageData;
        using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
            imageData = wc.DownloadData(url);
        return new MemoryStream(imageData);
     }
}
```

If I want to save cropped image I get the following error:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+
>
> InnerException: at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)

*I enable all permission for write on server.*

What should I do to save cropped images?

Comment: The exception is not specific enough to reliably diagnose what went wrong.  In general you'd have to assume that it could not write the file.  Easier to diagnose by putting File.WriteAllText(path, "") before the Save() call.  The snippet has a glaring bug that otherwise explains the mishap easily, it forgets to call img.Dispose().  That leaves a lock on the file, saving an image again with the same filename will fail.  Favor the `using` statement.

Comment: But why it's worked properly on localhost?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the address.  The exception is flaky because it only goes wrong the 2nd time and only when the garbage collector did not yet run.  Using Dispose() is a rock-hard requirement to make it reliable.  Not disposing the memory stream does not score any elegance points either, but is not critical.  If there is something else wrong, like the user account not having write access to the directory, then the File.WriteAllText trick should have given you a better diagnostic.

Comment: I've got this error when use `File.WriteAllText  ` `Could not find a part of the path 'c:\wwwroot\currentuser\example.com\wwwroot\Images\UsersImages\`

Comment: are you missing a filename? I can only see the folder path

Comment: The entire `Stream` and `Bitmap` are irrelevant. `imageData` contains exactly the bytes you need; just write them to a file. Involving two disposable classes for no reason just increases the chances of everything going wrong. As noted though, it seems that your `data.fileName` is simply never filled in.